# What is the shorthand for this?

Tags: jquery, toggle, jquery-hover

Here's some messy javascript:

```
$('.menu').mouseover(function () {
    $(this).animate({
    }, 500, function() {});
}).mouseout(function () {
    $(this).animate({
    }, 500, function() {});
});
```

How can I make this smaller, not minify, but isn't there a way to say like `"toggle"` instead of `"mouseover"` then `"mouseout"`?

thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for [`hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

Comment: Cool. So when I remove "mouse out" and just have hover, how do I specify what happens on mouse leave? Does it automatically do the opposite of what I specified?

Comment: @JacksonGariety No, you provide two callback arguments, the first for `mouseenter` and the second for `mouseleave`

Comment: oh sweet, got it. Good example in jQuery documentation, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

[jQuery `.hover()` combines `.mouseenter()` and `.mouseleave()` into one convenient method.](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)  It should also be noted that `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` work somewhat differently, and usually much better, than `mouseover` and `mouseout`.

```
$('.menu').hover(
    function () {
        $(this).animate({
        }, 500, function() {});
},
    function () {
        $(this).animate({
        }, 500, function() {});
});
```

Comment: @Jackson, you're welcome.  I did not see any other answers show your code in an example.

Answer (score 2):

Use .hover instead of mouseover mouseout. http://api.jquery.com/hover/ as you can see it takes handler in and handler out this will do what you want in mousein and out

Answer (score 0):

Yes, have a look at the `hover` function:

http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: `toggle()` serves an entirely different purpose

Comment: @Phil - Jumped the gun... Changed my answer.